# Do dates of service fall in between membership date range

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables one is the customer_service table with dates of service and the other is the membership table where the member can exist multiple times if they have had lapses in their membership effective and expiration dates. Below is a basic example of how these table might layout.

How might I find dates of service that fall outside or in between membership date ranges. A simple join will not work with this due to the member possibly having multiple date ranges for their membership under the same ID. Would this require some form of iteration here? I am unsure as to the best way to approach this kind of issue.

Customer_Service Table

```
id | customers   | Dos
-------------------------
 1 | Rodney      | 01/18/2018
 2 | Jim         | 02/15/2018
 3 | Tom         | 01/01/2018
 1 | Rodney      | 02/15/2018
 3 | Tom         | 03/01/2018
```

Membership Table

```
id | Effective_date | End_date
-------------------------
 1 | 01/01/2017     | 12/31/2017
 1 | 02/15/2018     | 05/20/2018
 2 | 06/20/2016     | 01/25/2018
 2 | 02/25/2018     | 12/31/2099
 3 | 01/01/2018     | 06/01/2018
```

Comment: What will your Customer_Service table look like if a customer has more than one Date of Service?  It looks like you may need to normalize this out a bit further.

Comment: It will just add another line with the date of service. The main issue here is the identification of dates of service that fall outside or in between membership dates and how one would go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is below.  The query will identify rows in CUSTOMER_SERVICE where DOS does not fall between any periods in the membership table for that customer.

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE CS
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM MEMBERSHIP M
    WHERE CS.ID = M.ID
       AND DOS BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DATE AND END_DATE
)
```

Or alternatively:

```
 SELECT CS.* FROM CUSTOMER_SERVICE CS
 LEFT JOIN MEMBERSHIP M ON M.ID = CS.ID 
      AND DOS BETWEEN EFFECTIVE_DATE AND END_DATE
 WHERE M.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks these two definitely work, I like the where not exists.